# GitHub packages not found when restored from GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, github-for-windows, github-package-registry

I have two dotnet core GitHub private repositories:

- Repository B publish nuget packages to GitHub packages repository (private).
- Repository A consumes nuget packages published by repository B from GitHub packages repository.

I have access to both repositories with full permissions and I'm able to build the dotnet core app from Repository A by downloading nuget from GitHub packages repository after sign-in.

When I use GitHub Actions in CI/CD to build Repository A, it is not finding the packages published by Repository B (see trace below).

I'm using GITHUB_TOKEN for auth. My question is, what permission is needed for the oAuth token to get read access to packages from repository B and where to set it in the GitHub UI?

```
 NotFound https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mycompany/download/foo.net/index.json 116ms
```

Comment: You need the `Permission` `packages` (see https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/authenticating-with-the-github_token#permissions-for-the-github_token)

Comment: The permissions in the link you mentioned is what GITHUB_TOKEN inherits for current repo. Here I'm downloading packages from a different repo.

Comment: So you want to modify the permissions of the default token? I don't think that's possible. The GitHub Actions documentation recommends to create a PAT (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924036/3241243).

Comment: Note that the scenario is quite basic. We have many repos and library references are through nugets published to private packages repository. For now, I have worked around by using private access token. It will be nice to get GITHUB_TOKEN work for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In case of the private packages, you can add this step to add the nuget source in actions

```
   - name: " Set NuGET Source"
        working-directory: <Working Directory>
        run: nuget sources Add -Name "github" -ConfigFile nuget.config -Source <Github repo url> -UserName <username> -Password <Public Access Token> -StorePasswordInClearText
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that using Private Access Token works fine. Issue is with oAuth Token only

Comment: yes we can use that as a secrets in github anc access it when needed.